# Trouble passing a variable/parameter from cms tag to block

Tags: magento

I have this tag in my CMS:

```
{{block  type="catalog/product_new" column_count="3" blerg="moo" _productsCount="10" name="home.catalog.product.new"  alias="product_homepage"  template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

Note the variable **blerg=moo.**

Then in block/product/new.php I have:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{

protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();

        Mage::log("0:testing",null,'jase.log');
        Mage::log("1:".$this->blerg,null,'jase.log');
        Mage::log("2:".$blerg,null,'jase.log');
        Mage::log("3:".$this->getData('blerg'),null,'jase.log');
        Mage::log("4:".$this->getBlerg(),null,'jase.log');
```

Then in my log I see:

- 0:testing
- 1:
- 2:
- 3:
- 4:

Why can't I see my variable value - "moo"?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('blerg');
```

Comment: Your code worked for me. Flush your cache and then try. Only 2nd case is wrong

Comment: :( I can't figure out what's wrong. I always did flush cache. I tried the following in __construct() as well as _beforeToHtml(): `Mage::log("0:testing2",null,'jase.log');
 Mage::log("1:".$this->blerg, null,'jase.log');
 Mage::log("2:".$blerg, null,'jase.log');
 Mage::log("3:".$this->getData('blerg'), null,'jase.log');
 Mage::log("4:".$this->getBlerg(), null,'jase.log');
 Mage::log("5:".Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('blerg'), null,'jase.log');` It outputted:                  `0:testing2
 1:
 2:
 3:
 4:
 5:` It's definitely firing. Just not working.

Comment: What is the Magento Version?